# Windows remove account-managment rights from a “Administrator” account

Tags: windows, user-accounts

How do I create a Administrator account
that has all the usual administrator rights except user management... (so this account cant change/create/delete user accounts)

Or put from other perspective:
how can I remove the user management rights
from a administrator account...

Comment: That would not make it an administrator anymore. What are you trying to achieve? In other words, why are you trying to do this? What's your goal that this is supposed to help you reach?

Comment: Well... the name is not the issue... call it "Supervisor" if you want... the objective is to have a user with the usual administrative rights of an administrator, except create/change/delete users... (I think this is completely explicit in the question)

Comment: Yes, that's clear from the question, but I think that's not your ultimate goal. You want to do this because it's your idea of a solution to some real-life problem. What's that real-life problem? (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029))

Comment: What I want is to delegate all the administrator function to other chosen user... except messing with accounts... the accounts can be only managed from my administrator account...